# How do I multiply a matrix to every third dimensional vector in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

For example, if I have an array

```
to_multiply = np.array([[[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [5,6,7]]])
```

And I want to multiply all the vectors in the 3rd dimension by a matrix. How would I do this
without using for loops?

To do this with for loops, I did

```
for x in range(1):
    for y in range(2):
        to_multiply[y, x] @= matrix
```

Comment: Does `matrix @ to_multiply` not produce the result you want? Could you provide an example of your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `numpy.matmul`,

> If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack of matrices
> residing in the last two indexes and broadcast accordingly.

Hence

```
to_multiply = np.matmul(to_multiply, matrix)
```

is same as

```
to_multiply = np.einsum('ijk,kl', to_multiply, matrix)
```

which is again same as

```
to_multiply @ matrix
```

for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `einsum` for that.

```py
np.einsum('ijk,kl', to_multiply, m)
```

Returns and array of the same shape as `to_multiply` (assuming that m is squared), whose each `[i,j]` subarray is `to_multiply[i,j] @ m`.

To be more accurate, what it does is return a 3d-array, whose element
`[i,j,l]` is the result of `Σk to_multiply[i,j,k]*m[k,l]`

So it computes

```py
for i in range(len(to_multiply)):
    for j in range(to_multiply.shape[1]):
        for l in range(m.shape[1]):
            res[i,j,l]=0
            for k in range(to_multiply.shape[2]): # that must be same as m.shape[0]
                res[i,j,l] += to_multiply[i,j,k]*m[k,l]
```

but, of course, that computation is not done in python, but in internal code of `einsum`, so it is fast.